# How to convert a string to a vb expression which includes control name in it

Tags: vb.net

.. eg: have a stri ng

```
strResult="controlName1.value * controlName2.value"
```

.. I need to change it to just controlName1.value * controlName2.value so that i can get the output as double value

Please reply

Thanks

Comment: What? Can you show what you've tried? Maybe that makes it clearer. `controlName1.value` is nothing which could be converted to a `Double` since it's just a ..... "controlName". Or is `controlName1.value` actually a double value as string?

Comment: look at this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1ec4e3f9-1512-47b0-8fe0-df9c89508799/execute-c-or-vbnet-string-at-runtime?forum=netfxbcl..  It seems you have to create your own parser

Comment: I already took the expression as a formula from user interface..just like "gridControl.Rows(i).cells("C1").value * gridControl.Rows(i).cells("C2").value" and these two cell values are double always. Let it be 10 and 20.. Now what happens is that am getting it as "gridControl.Rows(i).cells("C1").value * gridControl.Rows(i).cells("C2").value" just a string..I need to get 10 * 20 as the result..

Comment: strFormula = objExceFormula.strFormula
            Dim i As Integer = strFormula.IndexOf("[")
            Dim f As String = strFormula.Substring(i + 1, strFormula.IndexOf("]", i + 1) - i - 1)
            Dim repRes1 As String = strFormula.Replace("[", grdValFormat)
            Dim repRes2 As String = repRes1.Replace("]", """).Text)")

            Dim dtCostF As DataTable = New DataTable()
            Dim v As VariantType = dtCostF.Compute(repRes2, "")

Comment: strFormula ="gridControlName.Rows(i).cells("C1").value * gridControlName.Rows(i).cells("C2").value" if i write code like dblRes=gridControlName.Rows(i).cells("C1").value * gridControlName.Rows(i).cells("C2").value it wil give result.. but since its a string i couldnt get result

Comment: strFormula ="gridControlName.Rows(i).cells("C1").value * gridControlName.Rows(i).cells("C2").value"  can i remove those double quotes shown for every string variable through some code sneppets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi guys thanks for your updates.. I wrote my own function by using your concepts and some other code snippets .I am posting the result

Function generate(ByVal alg As String, ByVal intRow As Integer) As String
        Dim algSplit As String() = alg.Split(" "c)

```
    For index As Int32 = 0 To algSplit.Length - 1
        'algSplit(index) = algSplit(index).Replace("#"c, "Number")
        If algSplit(index).Contains("[") Then
            Dim i As Integer = algSplit(index).IndexOf("[")
            Dim f As String = algSplit(index).Substring(i + 1, algSplit(index).IndexOf("]", i + 1) - i - 1)
            Dim grdCell As Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridCell = dgExcelEstimate.Rows(intRow).Cells(f)
            Dim dblVal As Double = grdCell.Value
            algSplit(index) = dblVal
        End If

    Next

    Dim result As String = String.Join("", algSplit)
    'Dim dblRes As Double = Convert.ToDouble(result)
    Return result
End Function
```

Thanks again every one.. expecting same in future

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows Forms, there is an indexer property that accepts the name of a sub-control as a string and returns the control if a match is found.  See:  [`Control.ControlCollection.Item` Property (`String`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1865435(v=vs.110).aspx).aspx

The straightforward alternative in all UI frameworks is to map `String`s to `Control`s like such:

```
Function MapStringToControl(ctlName As String) As Control
    Select Case ctlName
        Case "controlName1"
            Return controlName1
        Case "controlName2"
            Return controlName2
        Case Else
            Return Nothing
End Function
```

Of course note that there is no `.Value` property in Windows Forms--you need to do something like `Integer.Parse(ctl.Text)`.

Comment: I already took the expression as a formula from user interface..just like "gridControl.Rows(i).cells("C1").value * gridControl.Rows(i).cells("C2").value" and these two cell values are double always. Let it be 10 and 20.. Now what happens is that am getting it as "gridControl.Rows(i).cells("C1").value * gridControl.Rows(i).cells("C2").value" just a string..I need to get 10 * 20 as the result.. i mean 200 .. but i cant evaluate that string in the code..

Answer (score 0):

It depends what type of control it is. For example a `textbox` has a `.Text` property. A `NumericUpDown` control has a `.Value` property.

All you need to do is to convert the appropriate property to the appropriate type. So for TextBoxes:

```
Dim result as Double = CDbl(txtFoo.Text) * CDbl(txtBar.Text)
```

For a NumericUpDown:

```
Dim result as Double = CDbl(nudFoo.Value) * CDbl(numBar.Value)
```

Comment: strFormula ="gridControlName.Rows(i).cells("C1").value * gridControlName.Rows(i).cells("C2").value" if i write code like dblRes=gridControlName.Rows(i).cells("C1").value * gridControlName.Rows(i).cells("C2").value it wil give result.. but since its a string i couldnt get result